# How to read the user-selected cell in an open Excel file via a C# application?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm tasked with extracting information from different kinds of spreadsheets and plugging them into a standardized one for future processing. OpenXML is being utilized to actually transfer the data and that part works fine, however I'm running into a snag deciding how to reliably determine where the data I want is located since the layout and available information will vary drastically.

It seems like it would be feasible to open the Excel file and prompt the user to select the cells I want them to, then programmatically save that selection and build a profile for future use. (For example, I can ask them to select the column where "name" is located.) I'm fairly new to C#, so any direction is appreciated!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.